# LibGdx Box2D: Can you set the localAnchorA/B in a rope joint?

Tags: box2d, libgdx

In a DistanceJointDef you can set localAnchorA and localAnchorB (both are Vector2) with this line:

```
jointDef.initialize(bodyA, bodyB, localAnchorA, localAnchorB);
```

However, I haven't seen any way for setting these same parameters in a RopeJointDef, in fact, they are declared as finals in the RopeJointDef class like this:

```
/** The local anchor point relative to bodyA's origin. **/
public final Vector2 localAnchorA = new Vector2(-1, 0);

/** The local anchor point relative to bodyB's origin. **/
public final Vector2 localAnchorB = new Vector2(1, 0);
```

So, my question is, is there any way to change these parameters?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the local anchors in rope joint by calling this statements

```
RopeJointDef ropeJointDef = new RopeJointDef();
ropeJointDef.localAnchorA.set(10,20);
ropeJointDef.localAnchorB.set(10,20);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just forgot about the Vector2 functions ... However, now I realize that ropes are not flexible so I will probably end up using the DistanceJoint XD, thanks